# How to loop through elements where the elements not added to the dom

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How to loop through elements where the elements were added with jquery?

```
// Added by JS
<div class="container">
 <div class="item">a</div>
 <div class="item">b</div>
 <div class="item">c</div>
</div>

// In document ready()
$('.item').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  console.log(text); // Nothing. Expecting a, b, c
})
```

My event for any of the elements would be

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item', function() {...})
```

`on` only works with events so how to get the loop, please?

Comment: Use same APIs  `$('.item').each(function() {`

Comment: Yes but noting in my console.

Comment: When do you want to loop? When the element is added?

Comment: The logic is the same, you just need to either select them after the have been appended to the DOM, or loop over the variable which contains the reference to them, eg: `$createdElements.each()`

Comment: Add a selector that already exist before `.item`. for eg, `body`
`$('body .item').each(function(){ // code here}`